# Does private key belong to one public key in Bitcoin?

Tags: private-key, copay

More address belong to one wallet in Copay. I have a 12-word mnemonic to my old Copay wallet, but not the private key. If I would infer the private key of the 12-word could I reach all the public adresses with that private-key and start withdrawal?

Comment: If you were to translate the mnemonic into the seed value it represents & feed that through the correct (I'm guessing bech32) PRNG algorithm, then yes, you could generate all of the private keys to spend the btc in all of the addresses in your Ciopay wallet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each private key corresponds to one public key, but a mnemonic key contains the master private key which describes how each private key is generated.

If you want to withdraw from it, I would use Electrum. It can show you the addresses and you can export individual private keys.

Comment: While each private key *technically* only corresponds to 1 public key, the compressed and uncompressed versions of that pubkey correspond to 2 very different wallet addresses. ... might be worth noting.

Comment: Also, and more importantly, the mnemonic passphrase IS NOT for a "private key," but instead is for a "seed value" that is fed into a PRNG (pseudo-random number generator) that derives a list of private keys. The seed value neither is a private key, nor describes how to generate any. It is simply a "bookmark" that sets the PRNG to start "reading" on the right "page" of a near-infinitely long "book" of potential keys it can generate.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your other question, but the public key and private key always work in a pair.  So one public key and one private key have to work together.  It is a one to one relationship.